# How to select each value for xml node sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml, xmlnode, sqlxml

I have an xml column within my sql server table where the XML looks like this:

```
<Alternate>
    <Suggestion>
        <Details>
            <Number>51</Number>
        </Details>
    </Suggestion>
    <Suggestion>
        <Details>
            <Number>53</Number>
        </Details>
    </Suggestion>
</Alternate>
```

I want to be able to pull out each value for the Number tag into a column that would look like this:

```
Number
51
53
```

I have attempted this using CROSS APPLY but it only pulls out the first value for each row:

```
Number
51
51
```

The SQL Query i wrote for this looks like this:

```
SELECT [XML].value('(//Alternate/Suggestion/Details/Number)[1]','nvarchar(255)') as Improvement_Number
FROM Table
CROSS APPLY [XML].nodes('(//Aternate/Suggestion/Details/Number)') AS T2(Improv)
```

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong with this please?
Any help would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating the table and inserting a row like this:

```
create table alternate ([XML] xml)

insert into alternate values (N'<Alternate>
    <Suggestion>
        <Details>
            <Number>51</Number>
        </Details>
    </Suggestion>
    <Suggestion>
        <Details>
            <Number>53</Number>
        </Details>
    </Suggestion>
</Alternate>')
```

You can query it in this way:

```
select 
    b.Improv.value('.', 'nvarchar(255)') Number
from 
    alternate a
    cross apply a.[XML].nodes('//Alternate/Suggestion/Details/Number') b(Improv)
```

Result:

```
Number
51
53
```